# Calculate the radial velocity of the target in a radar system

Tags: vectors, matlab, projection

I was asked to calculate the radial velocity $v_r$ with MATLAB of the radar system as shown below:

[image: A Doppler Radar system]

We know that the radar is at [0, 0], the target is at [50, 35] and its velocity vector ($v$) is [-6, 2]m/s.

I don't know how to do it in MATLAB without knowing the angle of $v_r$ and $v$. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks so much!

Comment: Without knowing the angle between $v_r$ and $v$ the former can be anything between zero and $v$. However, we know the angle because $v_r$ is parallel to $(50,35)$.

Comment: Project the velocity vector of the target onto the negative of the vector from the origin to the target.

Comment: $$v_r = \dfrac{v\cdot t}{\|t\|^2}t$$ $$\|v_r\| = \dfrac{|v\cdot t|}{\|t\|}$$ where $t$ is the vector from radar to target.